# Hyper-V Role and Hyper-V Server 2016

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2016

As per my knowledge, Hyper-V can be installed in Windows Sever 2016 by two ways; with PowerShell or with Server Manager. And I believe Hyper-V is an inbuilt feature of Windows Sever 2016 that I need to enable/add with PowerShell/ Server Manager.

However, I see Hyper-V Server 2016 is available as an iso file at

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-hyper-v-server-2016

Also I downloaded it from the above link.

Please clarify:

1. In spite of inbuilt feature of Hyper-V with Windows Sever 2016, why do I need an iso of Hyper-V Server 2016 or in which scenario it may be required?
2. If both (inbuilt Hyper-V and Hyper-V Server 2016) are different, how both are different?
3. Apart from adding/enabling Hyper-V on Windows Server 2016, can I install Hyper-V Server 2016 iso on Window Server 2016? If yes, please let me know, how?

I believe I elaborated my queries well.

Please resolve my all queries.

Regards

InTech

Answer (score 2):

Just expand the *description* in your [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-hyper-v-server-2016) and it will tell you clearly the purpose of this Hyper-V Server 2016 download option:

> The Windows hypervisor technology in Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2016 is
>   the same as what's in the Microsoft Hyper-V role on Windows Server
>   2016. It is a stand-alone product that contains only the Windows hypervisor, a Windows Server driver model, and virtualization
>   components. It provides a simple and reliable virtualization solution
>   to help you improve your server utilization and reduce costs.

I'm pretty sure this covers all your question:

1. No, you don't need it. It's just an option.
2. How they are different... yep, covered.
3. Nope. You don't install it on Windows Server 2016 as it already has it. You install it only if its virtualization is the only feature of Windows Server 2016 you need.

Comment: As Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2016 iso available on https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-hyper-v-server-2016 is an optional and a stand-alone product. Can I install it on stand-alone computer? If yes, please let me know, how? Is like installing Windows 7/8.1/10 with bootable USB stick?

Comment: It's similar to Server Core installation as Hyper-V Server doesn't have a GUI.